# Are there fixed names for patterns being used by Facebook, Android Market(famous apps)

Tags: design-patterns, android

Is there a fixed name for pattern like Facebook's current sliding dashboard style pattern, 
or the swiping tabs in Android Market

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Android Market Navi** is based on association of two elements: [Carousel](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/carousel) & [Slideable top navigation](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/slideable-top-navigation) (Sliding tabs)

> The bright example of carousel element is switching of albums in iPod. Sliding tabs is an example of the widespread tabs adapted under management by gestures for touch devices. The difference between them consists in initial appointment & gestures. Carousel navigation element was used for a navigation/choice of a concrete element, while tabs for navigation for groups of elements. It is underlined in a difference of gestures for focus: Slide for Carousel vs. Slide & Tap for focus tab.

**Facebook app** based on [Horizontal scrolling layout](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/horizontal-scrolling-page-indicators).

> It usually used together with the visual menu: same as Page indicators or layout indicators for multi direction scrolling. Good practice considers the fixed arrangement of an element of management, for example at a scrolling in extreme left placing you always will find search in Apple devices.

Comment: I really dislike those sliding tabs. I just don't think the metaphor is strong enough, with the 3D cylinder thing.

Comment: Actually is only two possible ways to visualize control element: plain and volume. For touch-interfaces volume control element more native owing to copying of model of interaction habitual in life.

Comment: Dan, sorry to confuse.  Did not mean your answer was incorrect.  I just don't like the control.  The call to action is not clear enough and I have seen people struggle with how it works.

Comment: No problem and thanx (: I agree with you about interaction, and the behavior of users in this case is quite explainable, though the volume control element model is much better plain